# How to compose the Bayer Raw10 data by C/C++ effectively?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, image-processing

Compose two raw image buffers:

1. The Bayer raw data including 10 bits per one pixel;
2. a raw buffer has 4192x3104 pixels
3. simply add the corresponding bit data
4. using C/C++ lang
5. on the Android mobile platform

How to compose the two raw buffers **effectively**?

Now, I try to do it like this:

1. read 8 pixels from rawBuf1 and rawBuf2, since I can use a 16 bit array (`unsigned short pixelWord[5]`) with 5 lengths to store them( 8X10 bits = 5x16 bits)
2. I do like this: the p0 `unsigned short p0 = (unsigned short )((pixelWord1[0] & 0X03FF) +(pixelWord2[0] & 0X03FF))`, etc.

But the upper is too inefficient.

Comment: Are you sure that the pixel uses 10 bits?  It is usually a multiple of 8 such as 8, 16, 24, 32 etc.

Comment: What are you asking for? Are you interested in space or performance efficiency? In what format do you get the raw data?

Comment: @Michael J I am sure.

Comment: It matters greatly how whether the order you store the pixels lines up with the order you read/write the pixels. After you lined that up you can take a look toward SSE/AVX intrinsics (make sure you enabled all optimization to see if your compiler can't figure it out by itself) if x86 is your only target platform (or altivec/NEON for other platforms) and if that is still not in the ballpark of your expectations you might have to to turn to multi-threading.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche I am interested in performance effciency. Raw data is just from Camera Sensor according the MIPI interface.

Comment: I don't know the MIPI interface. How do you get the pixels from the camera sensor? What is the API looking like? Do you get the pixels patched together or do you get the pixels separate as 32 bit values?

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche I have edited the question. In fact, you maybe do not care about how the data from. I can tell you that the datas are stored in a imageBuffer consecutively. I have a big problem : the data are 10 bits per pixel, and the memory are 8 bits per byte. And we cannot access the memory using 10 bits directly. So the conversion costs much time.

Comment: Ok, this means the pixel data is packed together?

Comment: Is there a risk of overflow when adding? Do you need to clamp when so?

Comment: What are your speed constraints that make the above access too slow?  Modern cpus are very fast.  Are you animating the data in real time?

Comment: @Bgie I will deal with it

Comment: What is the endianness of the platform? And how do you get the pixels, MSB first or LSB first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pixel data comes as a stream of bytes, stored in a raw buffer

```
unsigned char rawBuf1[100], rawBuf2[100];
```

Depending on the endianness of your platform, you might try [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) and let the compiler figure out, how to access the pixels

```
struct pixels0 {
    unsigned long long p0 : 10;
    unsigned long long p1 : 10;
    unsigned long long p2 : 10;
    unsigned long long p3 : 10;
    unsigned long long p4 : 10;
    unsigned long long p5 : 10;
};

struct pixels6 {
    unsigned long long pad : 4;
    unsigned long long p6 : 10;
    unsigned long long p7 : 10;
};
```

You would use this as

```
unsigned short p0 = ((struct pixels0*)&rawBuf1[0])->p0 + ((struct pixels0*)&rawBuf2[0])->p0;
/* ... */
unsigned short p5 = ((struct pixels0*)&rawBuf1[0])->p5 + ((struct pixels0*)&rawBuf2[0])->p5;
unsigned short p6 = ((struct pixels6*)&rawBuf1[7])->p6 + ((struct pixels6*)&rawBuf2[7])->p6;
unsigned short p7 = ((struct pixels6*)&rawBuf1[7])->p7 + ((struct pixels6*)&rawBuf2[7])->p;
```

But be aware, that this is highly platform and compiler dependent, if it works at all.

Comment: what's the memory layout of the **struct pixels** ?

Comment: By the way , is there any way to define a 10 bits data type in C?

Comment: I tried to use the way what you told. However, I found it's difficult to get the right data from the rawBuf array.For example, the bit data of bit[10...19] (the bit[0...9] is p0) in rawBuf stands for p1, I cannot simply use the code to get it. **((struct pixels*)&rawBuf1[0])->p1**

Comment: What do you mean with difficult? Why can't you use the code to get the second pixel?

Comment: the data is stored in the buffer one by one. For example, the p0's bit data in the buffer is bit[0...9], and the p1's bit data in the buffer is bit[10...19]... So p0 is between first byte and second byte, and p1 is between second byte and third byte. If we use the **struct pixels**, pixels.p0(using 16 data type--unsigned short, not unsigned long long, as it will occupy much memory)will start with 0X601060(address of **struct pixels**), but pixels.p1 will start with 0X601060 + 0X02 = 0X601062.

Comment: In fact, the pixels.p1 is in the bit[2...7] of 0X601061 and bit[0...3] of 0X601062. So the pixels.p1 is not correct.

Comment: From your comment, I conclude, you haven't tried the code. `struct pixels` is composed of a [bit field](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), each member occupying exactly 10 bits. If you use an `unsigned short`, you get holes between the members. To avoid the holes and have the members packed together, you must use a data type, large enough to hold all eight pixels.

Comment: But I can't. There isn't a data type which its sizeof(dataType) is 10 (8X10=80bit, 10 byte)

Comment: Yes, you're right. You only get the first six pixels.

Comment: See updated answer. You can split the struct and insert some padding.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. According your answer and comments, I have some ideas about my project. So I accept the answer. Thanks again.